# How to match second/further text nodes with XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
  foo
  <span>bar</span>
  baz
</div>
<div>bazinga</div>
```

I can use the XPath expression `//div[normalize-space(text())='foo']` to match the `<div>` node.

But what if I don't know `foo` but I know `baz` - is there a way I can match the node by it's second/third text node?

Answer (score 0):

You can index the node that you want to match:

```
//div[normalize-space(text()[2])='baz']
```

The above expression matches the second `text()` child of `div` elements.

Another (more specific) variant is this:

```
//div[normalize-space(text()[1]) = 'baz' or text()/normalize-space(following-sibling::text()) = 'baz']
```

This does check the first normalized `text()` value and after that all normalized following siblings for the value `baz`. But this only works with XPath-2.0, so I didn't mention it before.

In all three cases the result for your example is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: Does the second one not match `<div>bazinga</div>`? I thought of `contains()` but ruled it out because I though it will erroneously match other nodes.

Comment: @AndreKR: You were right. I added a more specific solution, but this one has the disadvantage that it needs an XPath-2.0 capable processor. If that doesn't work, I can't help you any further.

Comment: I don't think browsers have XPath 2.0. Anyway, your very first solution with the index works just fine.

Comment: Yes. Browsers only support XPath-1.0/XSLT-1.0. But I really can't think of a general solution for XPath-1.0... So I'm glad that your needs seem to be satisfied by the first approach.